# Simple like/unlike button with rails 3, jquery, and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a product, user, and like model. A user can like a product. I am trying to implement a simple like button which, upon a click, allows a user to like a product. Then the like button transforms into an unlike button, allowing the user to unlike a product. Pretty straightforward.

I have implemented the model/controller logic for the above. I am not very good with javascript/ajax and was wondering what the best way would be to implement the above functionality. I want the like/unlike actions to be handled via ajax. I am using rails 3 and jquery ujs for my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My answer to your question is long, so I wrote up an [example application](https://github.com/invisiblefunnel/soquestion6482354). Here's a snippet:

There are many ways to skin this cat, but I like to render a partial and a single ujs template.

`_like_button.html.erb`:

```
<% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_product_id(@product.id) %>
  <%= form_for like, :html => { :method => :delete },
                     :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Unlike" %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for current_user.likes.build(:product_id => @product.id), :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Like" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`toggle.js.erb`, where `"#like"` is the div enclosing the form:

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render('like_button') %>");
```

Comment: Man, its so awesome that you did this. Your sample app really helped me understand how this works.  Thx a ton!

Comment: @dwhalen, I cannot find the linked sample application anymore. I am trying to do the same thing in my app, and I have almost identical code in my application. The first time around everything works fine, the Like button shows up, and on clicking it, it toggles to unlike. However, when I try to click the unlike button, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: How can I add something to the database so that I can actually view this sample in action?

Comment: Follow the readme: https://github.com/invisiblefunnel/soquestion6482354#getting-started. `rake db:seed`.

Comment: @dwhalen, thanks a lot for the example! I understand better now :) I only have one problem : when I click "Unlike", I get an error in the log `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Like with id=11):
  app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:9:in `destroy'`. The "Unlike" does not get updated to "Like" until I click again... Do you know why?

Comment: Nice sample app, i just wish it was complete so we can see your sample app in action.

Comment: FYI you can find the source for the example app at the following forks: https://github.com/shihabullal/soquestion6482354, https://github.com/shihabullal/soquestion6482354, https://github.com/sergeylukin/soquestion6482354, https://github.com/haon/soquestion6482354

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to make your links work via AJAX, you just need to provide `link_to` with `:remote => true` argument. But I guess you want to make some sort of feedback to the user. Take a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) screencast.